# (unix/bash) Details of using ">>" with terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I'm trying to understand how ">>" works. Does it use auto-append mode or lseek?

I've downloaded the bash source and have been trying to grep my way through to find how it works, but I've been unsuccessful. Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to know, since this works via system calls, is to run bash with strace. You can do something like:

```
$ strace -o bash.log bash
$ echo hello >> test.txt
$ echo goodbye >> test.txt
$ exit
$ grep test.txt bash.log
open("test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
open("test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
write(3, "echo hello >> test.txt\necho good"..., 48) = 48
```

You can see by the flags passed to the `open()` calls, that it's opened in append mode directly.